# How to dequeue UITableViewCells that conform to a defined protocol

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, protocols

I'd like to make sure that my tableview only contains cells that conform to a said protocol. I simplified the implementation to illustrate the specific problem.

```
    protocol ACommonLookAndFeel {
       func configureMyLookAndFeel() 
    }

    CellA: UITableViewCell, ACommonLookAndFeel
    CellB: UITableViewCell, ACommonLookAndFeel

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var cell: UITableViewCell   

        if indexPath.row == 0 {          
             cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellA", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CellA
             if let myCell = cell as? CellA {
                 myCell.configureMyLookAndFeel() // we need to call this for each cell
             }
        } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellB", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CellB
            if let myCell = cell as? CellB {
               myCell.configureMyLookAndFeel() // we need to call this for each cell
            }
        }
        return cell
     }
```

The above code is working except that there is repeated code and I need to do the casting each time to access the configureMyLookAndFeel() method. As I want all my cells to be configured for the look and feel, I tried the code below instead but hit the compile error

**Error: Cannot convert return expression of type 'protocol' to return type 'UITableViewCell'**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell: protocol <ACommonLookAndFeel>   

    if indexPath.row == 0 {          
         cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellA", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CellA
    } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellB", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CellB
    }

    cell.configureMyLookAndFeel() // works
    return cell // Compiler Error !
 }
```

1. Is there a way to fix this compiler error?
2. Ideally I wouldn't have like to avoid repeating the call to dequeueCell and the casting to **CellA** or **CellB**. I know what cell I need to cast it to based on the **cellReuseIdentifier** which is the same as my cell class name. Is there a way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell: UITableViewCell

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellA", forIndexPath: indexPath) // There is no need to cast here
    } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellB", forIndexPath: indexPath) // There is no need to cast here
    }

    // The method will be called for all cells that conform to ACommonLookAndFeel.
    // This is also safe, so no crash will occur if you dequeue a cell that 
    // doesn't conform to ACommonLookAndFeel. Depending on the behavior
    // you want to achieve, you may want to use a ! instead of ? to force
    // a crash in case of issues while developing your app.
    (cell as? ACommonLookAndFeel)?.configureMyLookAndFeel()

    // You have to return a UITableViewCell, not a ACommonLookAndFeel
    return cell 
}
```

Comment: I also tried var cell: ProtocolName to no avail. I still get the same compiler error.  My protocol's only function is the configureMyLookAndFeel() which sets the tableview cell background color and transform to rotate it 180 degrees

Comment: Sorry I misread the error you were getting. I edited my answer, look at it again.